# Spring Security configure httpsecurity

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm taking my first try on the Spring Security and really got stuck on such a task: i have a default webpage, which should be defaulty non-authenticated, and i have a batch of controller calls, which i want to secure with a PreAuthorized annotation. The basic idea is, that i want to disable the default "redirect to login page", but still have the opportinity to operate the Spring Security's method security complex.

I'm using a java configuration, which looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/res/**"); // #3
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();        
    }
}
```

I know(or seem to understand) that by this point all of my calls should be permitted(have been sitting over this for the past two days, and clearly running out of ideas).

The Controller's method, which i want to secure, is:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value="/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAdminPage(Model model){
    return "admin";
}
```

I know that i can use antMatcher to add "/**/admin" and authorize the calls to the specific url, but the general idea is:

1. Disable the "go to login page" on the root(and other random controller mappings).
2. Do a manual ajax based authentication from a ajax drop down(or something).
3. When a random non-autherised user bumps in a page, which has a @PreAuthorized on a Controller, then, and only then, he should be redirected.

UPD: the basic question is to invoke the redirect to login page only on access denied scenario, allowing the anonymous role for basic site view's and calls.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question(maybe not as clean as it should look).

1. You can config the Spring Security Http Security so it wont ask to login on every page:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
   ```
2. To enable the method security(the PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") and ect), you need to add an annotation:

   ```
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   ```

after which you need to add to the HttpSecurity object something to catch the exceptions of "Access Denied and ect" (found this on some other stackoverflow question thread):

```
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {

            @Override
            public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                if (authException != null) {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    response.getWriter().print("Unauthorizated....");
                }
            }
        });
```

And now you can secure your controller and other components with @PreAutherized. Hope this will help someone.

But there still remains one thing - when the user is unauthorized and i try to reach some preAuthorized page, the above mentioned exception handler is invoked, returning the "Unauthorized..." message. But when the user is authorized and i try a page with a diffirent preAuthorized role, i get the default 403 Access Denied.